# Java boolean value is always true

Tags: java, constructor, boolean

I'm having trouble with my school Java code - I'm trying to create a constructor that takes a boolean value, and then uses it later, but for some reason it's always true. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm posting my entire code, I thought redacting it a little would make my problem clearer, but it seems it only created confusion.

```
        import java.util.*;
public class L3_Z6 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    class FunnyString{
        private boolean ascii;
        private String slowo;
        private char separator;


        public FunnyString (String slowo, char separator, boolean ascii){
            this.slowo=slowo;
            this.separator=separator;
            this.ascii=ascii;

        }
        public FunnyString (String slowo, char separator){
            this(slowo, separator, false);
        }
        public FunnyString (String slowo, boolean ascii){
            this(slowo,'-', ascii);
        }
        public FunnyString (String slowo){
            this(slowo,'-', false);
        }
        public void setAscii (boolean a){
            ascii=a;
        }
        public void setChar (char b){
            separator=b;
        }

        public String toString (){

            int dlugosc = slowo.length();
            int licznik = 0;
            String wynik="";
            do{
                if(ascii=false){
                wynik+=slowo.charAt(licznik);
                }
                if(ascii=true){
                    wynik+=(int)slowo.charAt(licznik);
                }
                if(licznik!=dlugosc-1)
                    wynik+=separator;
                licznik++;
            }while (licznik!=dlugosc);
            wynik+="\n";

            return wynik;
        }
    }
          FunnyString w1=new FunnyString("Kaktus");
          FunnyString w2=new FunnyString("Eukaliptus",'*');  
          FunnyString w3=new FunnyString("Yuka",true);

          System.out.println(w1);

          System.out.println(w2);

          System.out.println(w3);

          w1.setAscii(true);
          w1.setChar('*');
          System.out.println(w1);

          w3.setAscii(false);
          w3.setChar('!');
          System.out.println(w3);



}


}
```

Comment: How did you confirm that `ascii` is always true? Also, what is `slowo`? This is incomplete code. How do you expect us to solve the issue with incomplete code?

Comment: show the `later` part we dont know how you tried to print?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: I cut out parts where I actually used all of those values. If i'd just create a      if(ascii=true){System.out.println("it's true"), it would always print out that string.

Comment: Now I feel really dumb, but it works. Thanks Toumash!

Comment: Yes, please show us the code and results of how you are verifying ascii is "always true". Based on your code above, for w1 it should be false, for w2 it should be false, for w3 it should be true. It's possible the error is in your evaluation code, not your constructors. (Example, your IF check should use double-equals (asci == true).

Comment: when condition become assignment then it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `if` conditions, you're using assignment instead of comparison.

Change this

```
if(ascii=false){
    wynik+=slowo.charAt(licznik);
}
if(ascii=true){
    wynik+=(int)slowo.charAt(licznik);
}
```

to this

```
if(ascii==false){
    wynik+=slowo.charAt(licznik);
}
if(ascii==true){
    wynik+=(int)slowo.charAt(licznik);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be using your option

```
FunnyString w3=new FunnyString("something",true);
```

and once you've set your boolean variable to true, you may be not re-sseting it, so it keeps the 'true' value.

Default value for boolean is 'false', so debug your code, I'm sure it will help you find where is your error.

If you want to, post here your entire code, and we will help you.